# How to redirect my url with white spaces in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to 301-redirect an url. For other pages it hasn't been a problem but this concerns a pdf, and the old url contained spaces. (Maybe that's the problem?) I've tried many things, but it just doesn't seem to work. Depending on what I try, I get a 404 or a 500 error.

Old url = http://www.duo-dodo.com/img/pers/PERSBERICHT%20-%20Dodo%20The%20Resurrection%20-%208%20juni%202015.pdf

should redirect to

New url = http://www.duo-dodo.com/img/pers/PERSBERICHT-Dodo-The-Resurrection-13-juli-2015.pdf

I'm a beginner so it might be a stupid question, but I read many articles on Stack Overflow on the subject and none of the solutions seemed to work for me. I hope someone can help me? 
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?img/pers/PERSBERICHT\s-\sDodo\sThe\sResurrection\s-\s8\sjuni\s2015.pdf$ /img/pers/PERSBERICHT-Dodo-The-Resurrection-13-juli-2015.pdf [NC,L]
```

"\s" in regex matches a single space.